# Changing game controls for android device using C# in unity2D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a breakout style game built for web that uses mouse to move the paddle left and right and when clicked the ball launches. what i am trying to achieve is have this running on my android device with the correct controls as at the moment upon testing it does not work well at all as the moment i touch the screen on the phone the ball launches and the paddle controls move strange! here are the scripts for the paddle and the ball if someone can help or point me right i will really appreciate it as only just finding my feet in unity.

```
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {

    private Ball ball;

    void Start(){
        ball = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Ball> ();
    }

    void Update () {
            MoveWithMouse ();
    }

    void MoveWithMouse(){
        Vector3 paddlePos = new Vector3 (4.7f, this.transform.position.y, 0f);
        float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition.x / Screen.width * 16;
        paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp (mousePosInBlocks, 4.7f, 11.3f);
        this.transform.position = paddlePos;
    }

}

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

    private Paddle paddle;

    private bool hasStarted = false;

    private Vector3 paddleToBallVector;

    void Start () {
        paddle = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Paddle> ();
        paddleToBallVector = this.transform.position - paddle.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!hasStarted) {
            //lock ball relative to the paddle
            this.transform.position = paddle.transform.position + paddleToBallVector;
            //wait for mouse press to start
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                hasStarted = true;
                this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (2f, 10f);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){

        Vector2 tweak = new Vector2 (Random.Range(0f,0.2f),Random.Range(0f,0.2f));

        if (hasStarted) {
            GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity += tweak;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the ball is launching is because `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` also returns true when the screen is touched on mobile. To counteract that, you may want to use the controls specific to mobile. If you want to release the ball when the finger is lifted for example... you can do:

```
if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
```

For moving the paddle with the finger position, you can put something like this in your update method:

```
if (Input.TouchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    paddlePos = new Vector3(touch.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    transform.position = paddlePos;
}
```